# ASP.NET MVC validation attribute: Updated property not used in validation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation

I need to be able to change input data before it is validated with validation attribute. For example in Sweden post code can contain space, like "111 22". I want to remove space before I validate it. I tried with below solution without any success.

I have a property with a validation attribute, StringLength(5). After submitting the form I update the property value when binding to view model class. My problem is that when validation occurs it uses the value that is posted before I changed it despite that I know that DefaultModelBinder is running after the set method. In below code example I thought both input values "111 22" and "11122" would work since in my set method I remove space from my string but "111 22" don't validate as expected.

Example Index.cshtml file

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Form", FormMethod.Post))
{
    Enter post code
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PostCode)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.PostCode)
    <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
}
```

Example view model class (Client.cs)

```
private string postCode = null;
[StringLength(5)]
public string PostCode {
    get { return this.postCode; }
    set
    {
        this.postCode = value?.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
    }
}
```

Example action method in controller

```
public ActionResult Index(Client client)
{
    return View(client);
}
```

I know that the set method in the property is called before the validation since I tried to override the DefaultModelBinder and then added a breakpoint to it. I have also made a custom validation attribute that inherits from StringLength to check which value that is validated. Any suggestions?

**A bonus question**, I am also wondering why the value that is returned after validation are binding the old value to the input control but if I just write the model property to the view (@Model.Name) I got the updated value.

Comment: What do you mean _it uses the old value_? And how would you expect `"111 22"` which is 6 characters to pass validation which only allows 5 characters? And what is the code for you custom ModelBinder and `StringLengthAttribute`?

Comment: I updated the question and I hope it is more clear now. With old value I meant the value before it is changed (set). Since I update the value and remove space I thought it would validate. I overrided them and added breakpoints only to see in which order they are called and which values that are used.

Comment: The `DefaultModelBinder` is not running after `set` method. The `DefaultModelBinder` **is** responsible for **setting** the value. And validation is based on the posted value (as read from the `ValueProvider`), not on the code in your setter. And you have said your have a `custom validation attribute` which you have not shown so we cannot guess what the code does.

Comment: I only created a custom validation to see what value is really validated. I am not using it. Only the code in the example. Okay, is it possible to set the value from the ValueProvider or is it bad practise doing that?

Comment: Terrible practice. Write your own validation attribute, or just check the value in the controller and add a `ModelStateError` and return the view.

Comment: If I use my own validation attribute I still can't change the input value. I really like the idea to have all validation in the view model class. Is there a solution where I change input data and validate it using attribute validation?

Comment: A validation attribute is for validating a value, NOT for changing it! If you ant to change the value, create a custom model binder.